# How do you say "hadn't made them" with didn't?

Tags: tense, verbs

"I didn't have this" is equivalent to "I hadn't this"

But is there an equivalent sentence to

"I hadn't made them"?

I can't think of one, because "I didn't made them" doesn't sound grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

*Have* has two different functions: it can be an auxiliary to form "perfect" constructions, or it can be used as a substantive verb meaning "possess" etc.

As an auxiliary, it **never** takes "do"-support: it forms negatives and questions directly:

> I have seen it.

> I haven't (have not) seen it.

> Have you seen it?

> I hadn't seen it.

etc.

As a substantive verb, it *can* form negatives and questions the same way;

> I hadn't any.

> Have they any?

but these forms are increasingly rare* and usually get replaced by "do"-support, like ordinary verbs:

> I didn't have any.

> Do they have any?

But your *have made them* is a perfect, and cannot take "do"-support.

*The use of substantive *have* without "do" support is more common in British than American English, but even here it is disappearing. Fifty years ago, *Do you have ...?* simply didn't occur in British English (except in a habitual sense, eg *Do you have dances in your village?*). The normal form was *Have you got ...?* or more formally, *Have you ...?* *Do you have...?* was something that we heard Americans saying.